# DRYing argument checks

Tags: ruby

There's a method that's usually called with named arguments and it looks like this

```
def foo(x = nil, y = nil)
  fail ArgumentError, "x must be present" unless x
  fail ArgumentError, "y must be present" unless y
  # do stuff with x and y
end
```

I want to rewrite as something like

```
def foo(x = nil, y = nil)
  required_arguments :x, :y
  # do stuff with x and y
end
```

or

```
class Foo
  required_arguments :bar, :x, :y

  def bar(x = nil, y = nil)
  end
end
```

I've tried to implement second approach with `alias_method_chain` but the problem is that `__method__` is evaluated in the context of my utility module so I can't access the parameters of the method I need to check. Any ideas?

Comment: if `x` and `y` **must** be present, then don't supply default values for them. Easy as pie.

Comment: Unfortunately, default values are required for named arguments with current Ruby version

Answer (score 3):

If you use ruby 2.0 you can use keyword arguments:

```
def foo(x: (fail ArgumentError), y: (fail ArgumentError))
  # do stuff with x and y
end
```

And in ruby 2.1 you have proper required arguments:

```
def foo(x:, y:)
  # do stuff with x and y
end
```

This way you do actually have named parameters (you called them named parameters in your question, but that's a bit confusing imho), so you have to call the method like this:

```
foo(x: 1, y: 2)
```

Comment: +1 from me, I use this technique, too. Sometimes, though, you want to do a bit more than just `fail ArgumentError`...

Answer (score 0):

The [value of such run-time assertions is limited](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ChickenTyping), but they do have their use. I have incorporated them in `YSupport`. Type `gem install y_support` in your command line, and use it as follows

```
require 'y_support/typing'

def foo x=nil, y=nil
  x.aT; y.aT
  # do stuff with x and y
end
```

Mnemonic: In `aT`, `a` means "assert" and `T` means `TypeError` – raise `TypeError` if the assertion fails. If `#aT` method is called without parameters, it simply enforces that the receiver must be truey. If a block is supplied, any assertion can be written. For example, the following call enforces that the receiver be divisible by 3:

```
6.aT { |n| n % 3 == 0 }  #=> 6
7.aT { |n| n % 3 == 0 }  #=> TypeError: 7:fixnum fails its check!
```

In case of checking the method arguments, `ArgumentError` is appropriate when there is wrong number of arguments and similar problems. When the arguments are of wrong type, I prefer to raise `TypeError`. Error message of `#aT` method can be customized with two string arguments. The first one describes what the receiver, the second one describes the block assertion. For example:

```
7.aT "number of apples", "be divisible by three" do |n| n % 3 == 0 end
#=> TypeError: Number of apples fails to be divisible by three!
```

The `#aT` method, if it passes, returns back its receiver, so the assertions can be chained:

```
81.aT( "no. of apples", "divisible by 3 ) { |n|
  n % 3 == 0
}.aT( "no. of apples", "be a square" ) { |n|
  root = n ** 0.5; root == root.floor
} ** 0.5 #=> 9.0
```

Other, more specialized runtime assertions are available in `YSupport`, such as:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].aT_kind_of Enumerable #=> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
:foobar.aT_respond_to :each
#=> TypeError: Foobar:symbol does not respond to method 'each'!
:foobar.aT_respond_to :each, "object returned from the black box"
#=> TypeError: Object returned from the black box does not respond to method 'each'!
7.aT_equal 8
#=> TypeError: 7:fixnum must be equal to the prescribed value (8:fixnum)!
```

You can look up more of those methods by yourself in `YSupport`, and if you miss something, you are welcome to contribute it.

As a post scriptum to this post, if you are accustomed to `ActiveSupport`'s `#present?` method, the runtime assertion for it in `YSupport` is:

```
[].aT_present "supplied array"
#=> TypeError: Supplied array not present!
```

Comment: Looks pretty cool, but I'd rather not monkey patch `Object`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I wrote it before refinements came into being. But anyway, a method name starting with `aE` is sufficiently rare in regular coding that it does not mess up the namespece that much. I did think about those things, and I think it is an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: @synapse: Also, monkey patched classes are not limited to `Object`. `Array` has eg. `Array#aT_includes` that enforces object presence, `Array#aT_uniq` that enforces uniqueness of the array objects... `Hash` has `Hash#aE_has` that enforces via `ArgumentError` that the hash in question has the given key...